# Global variable resetting itself in subroutine

Tags: perl, recursion, scope

Forgive me for the (probably) stupid question, but I'm messing around with this code (actually a model of something in a larger program), and something is throwing me off:

```
sub recurse { 
  my $m = shift; 
  $g .= "::" . $m; 
  if ($m == 0) { return $g; } 
  else { $m--; recurse ($m); }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
  my $g = '';
  $str = recurse (10); 
  print $str . "\n";
}
```

The first iteration of the 'for' loop works fine.  On subsequent iterations, however, I am having an issue.  As you can see, the global variable $g is reset first thing in the 'for' loop before the recursive function is called.  With the debugger, I can see that $g is set back to '' before the function is called.  However, as soon as the function 'recurse' is entered, it goes back to the previous value.  What am I missing here?

As a corollary, I don't like using a global variable here.  What is the 'correct' way to do it without making $g a parameter for recurse()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`my $g` is a local variable so it's not the same one you use inside `recurse`. Removing `my` will fix that, though it's still going to be an ugly code.

You can pass `$g` a second parameter to the `resurse` function.

Note: `use strict;` is your friend ;)

Comment: *sigh* I suppose you're right.  My laziness seems to be biting me in the butt.  I've fixed the code, and I'll post it below.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply move the definition of `g` outside the loop and before the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

As yi_H said, the `my $g` you declare inside the loop is a completely separate variable from the `$g` that `recurse` is using.  It works the first time because all variables start out as `undef`, which as a string becomes the empty string.  If you tried printing out `$g` inside the loop after calling `recurse`, you'd see it was still empty.  Using [strict](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?strict) helps catch this sort of error.  It might or might not have caught this case, depending on what the rest of your program looks like.

The easiest way to handle this is to pass `$g` as a parameter.  However, sometimes it's easier to use a recursive closure.  Note that Perl uses a reference-count garbage collector, which means it can't delete self-referential data structures (including a closure that has a reference to itself so it can call itself recursively) until the entire program exits. I use the [weaken](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3a%3aUtil#weaken) function from [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar%3a%3aUtil) to avoid that. `$strongRef` is used only to keep the coderef from being garbage collected before we're done with it.

```
use Scalar::Util 'weaken';

for (my $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
  my $g = '';

  my $recurse;
  my $strongRef = $recurse = sub {
    my $m = shift;
    $g .= "::" . $m;
    if ($m == 0) { return $g; }
    else { $m--; $recurse->($m); }
  };

  weaken($recurse); # Prevent memory leak

  my $str = $recurse->(10);
  print $str . "\n";
}
```

However, in this particular case, I'd probably just have the closure fill in `$str` directly instead of returning a value:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
  my $str = '';
  my $recurse;
  my $strongRef = $recurse = sub {
    my $m = shift;
    $str .= "::" . $m;
    if ($m-- > 0) { $recurse->($m); }
  };

  weaken($recurse); # Prevent memory leak

  $recurse->(10);
  print $str . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  I'm going to mark yi_H as the answer, tho, just because he answered first.

Answer (score 0):

As the old saying goes, hard work pays off, but laziness pays off *now*.  Here's what the code looks like now that I decided to stop being lazy, and do it the 'right' way (I also changed $g to an array, to avoid awkward leading separators):

```
use strict;

sub recurse {
  my $m = shift;
  my @g = qw();
  @g = @{$_[0]} if $_[0];
  push (@g, $m);
  if ($m == 0) { return @g; }
  else { $m--; recurse ($m, \@g); }
}


for ( my $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
  my @str = recurse (10);
  print join('::', @str) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: fyi, the for statement could have just been "for (0..2)"

Comment: A trick used to avoid the global and not have the second variable in the interface is to have a second private work function that is called by the public interface function.  eg, sub recurse{work_recurse shift, ()}

Answer (score 0):

> What is the 'correct' way to do it without making $g a parameter for recurse()

Easy, since `$g` is not needed at all.

```
sub recurse { 
  my $m = shift; 
  if ($m == 0) {
    return "::" . $m;
  } else {
    return "::" . $m . recurse($m-1);
  }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
  print recurse(10) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: True for this case, but the $m represents other work that needed to be done in the model.  One of the side-effects of using a model like this to represent more difficult code is that it's hard to tell what's a necessary part of the larger piece.

Comment: @coding_hero, So? I didn't change anything relating to `$m`. All I did is always return the result instead of sometimes adding it into a global variable. If you can do one, you can do the other just as easily. In fact, I dare say that avoiding the global actually simplifies things.